# Schema.org Organization URL markup issue

Tags: schema.org, microdata

In a web page each registered company has own profile page with a list of records belonging to a company. I'm using `Schema.org Organization` structured data for that page and that schema markup requires URL property. As I understand it should contain e.g company home page url. The problem is that we do not store that kind of information.

If company profile URL in our page is: `www.mypage.com/unique-company-profile` can I use same url in schema URL property or it has to be an URL with a different domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t require the `url` property for `Organization` (it never requires any property). Consumers (like Google Search) require properties for their features (like rich results). So, it’s perfectly fine to have an `Organization` without `url`; you might just not get a certain feature in a certain search engine.

As far as Schema.org is concerned, the [`url`](https://schema.org/url) property can have a site-internal URL as value. A common structure is to use `url` for your own page about the organization, and [`sameAs`](https://schema.org/sameAs) for the organization’s official site.

```html
<link itemprop="url" href="/organizations/acme" />
<a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://acme.example/">official site</a>
```

That said, again, a consumer might have certain restrictions; if you care about the feature they offer, you have to check their documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I forgot to mention, that google search console generated a ton of errors related to URL property. So as I understand using url from my own page is OK.

Comment: @DeividasJuškevičius: According to Schema.org, yes. If you have a specific Google Search feature in mind, they might have further restrictions on the `url` value.